# validations are working even after removing html

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, formvalidation-plugin

I have a form in which I have `addmore` functionality. On clicking addmore a set of html input fields append to the form and if a user want to delete the added row he/she can do that too. All is working fine just facing issue that after removing the appended html, validations are still working for the appended fields.

> I am using [ValidaionsJs](http://formvalidation.io/examples/) with bootstrap for validations.

Below is the error I am getting

> TypeError: $message is undefined
>
> $allErrors   = $message.find('.' + this.options.err.clazz.split('
>   ').join('.') +...

[image]

```
     var $parent      = $field.closest(row),
            $message     = $field.data(ns + '.messages'),
            $allErrors   = $message.find('.' + this.options.err.clazz.split(' ').join('.') + '[data-' + ns + '-validator][data-' + ns + '-for="' + field + '"]'),
            $errors      = validatorName ? $allErrors.filter('[data-' + ns + '-validator="' + validatorName + '"]') : $allErrors,
            $icon        = $field.data(ns + '.icon'),
            // Support backward
            container    = ('function' === typeof (this.options.fields[field].container || this.options.fields[field].err || this.options.err.container))
                            ? (this.options.fields[field].container || this.options.fields[field].err || this.options.err.container).call(this, $field, this)
                            : (this.options.fields[field].container || this.options.fields[field].err || this.options.err.container),
            isValidField = null;
```

Here is my html

```
<fieldset class="col-md-6">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove-addmore high-education  fa fa-trash-o" alt="Remove" title="Remove" onclick="removeAddmore(this)"></a>
    <div class="ph10"><legend>Higher Education</legend> </div>
    <div class="form-group ph10 mt10">
        <label for="">Title</label>
        <?php echo $this->Form->input('DoctorEducation.' . $count . '.title', array('placeholder' => 'ex. DM or Diploma', 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty-message' => __('notEmpty'))); ?>
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('DoctorEducation.' . $count . '.id');
    echo $this->Form->hidden('DoctorEducation.' . $count . '.user_id', array('value' => $userID));
    ?>
    <div class="form-group ph10 mt10">
        <?php
        $data = array(3);
        $GraduationDegries = array();
        foreach ($data as $idValue) {
            $GraduationDegries[$idValue] = $degreeTypes[$idValue];
        }
        $degreeTypes = $GraduationDegries;

        echo $this->Form->input('DoctorEducation.' . $count . '.degree_type_id', array('empty' => 'Select Course', 'label' => 'Course', 'div' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty-message' => __('notEmpty'), 'options' => $degreeTypes));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group ph10 mt10">
<?php echo $this->Form->input('DoctorEducation.' . $count . '.college_hospital', array('label' => 'College / Hospital Name', 'div' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty-message' => __('notEmpty'))); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="" class="ph10">Duration</label>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="input-group year">
<?php echo $this->Form->input('DoctorEducation.' . $count . '.start_date', array('placeholder' => 'Start Year', 'type' => 'text', 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty-message' => __('notEmpty'), 'div' => false)); ?>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="input-group year">
<?php echo $this->Form->input('DoctorEducation.' . $count . '.end_date', array('placeholder' => 'End Year', 'div' => false, 'type' => 'text', 'label' => false, 'class' => 'form-control', 'data-fv-notempty-message' => __('notEmpty'), 'div' => false)); ?>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

and here is the JS which I am using for removing HTML

```
function removeAddmore(_this) {
    //  $(_this).closest('fieldset').remove();

    var classname = $(_this).attr('class');
    if (classname.indexOf("post-education") >= 0) {
        console.log($("#higher_edu_count").val());
        var val = $("#higher_edu_count").val();
        $("#higher_edu_count").val(val - 1);
        $(_this).closest('fieldset').remove();
    } else if (classname.indexOf("past-exprience") >= 0) {
        var val = $("#higher_edu_count").val();
        $("#higher_edu_count").val(val - 1);
        $(_this).closest('fieldset').remove();
    } else if (classname.indexOf("high-education") >= 0) {
        var val = $("#higher_edu_count").val();
        $("#higher_edu_count").val(val - 1);
        $(_this).closest('fieldset').remove();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to stop the validations after removing the HTML.

Please let me know is there something I have to mention for more clarification

There are some useful links.

> http://formvalidation.io/examples/switching-validators-same-field/ 
>   http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/ 
>   http://formvalidation.io/examples/ignoring-validation/
>
> **Update**

Try the following code but no success

```
 function removeAddmore(_this) {
    //  $(_this).closest('fieldset').remove();

    var classname = $(_this).attr('class');
    if (classname.indexOf("post-education") >= 0) {
        var val = $("#higher_edu_count").val();
        $("#higher_edu_count").val(val - 1);
        //   $(_this).closest('fieldset').remove();
        $('#education').formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'data[DoctorEducation][1][title]', false);
        $('#education').formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'data[DoctorEducation][1][degree_type_id]', false);
        $('#education').formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'data[DoctorEducation][1][college_hospital]', false);
        $('#education').formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'data[DoctorEducation][1][start_date]', false);
        $('#education').formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'data[DoctorEducation][1][end_date]', false);
    } else if (classname.indexOf("past-exprience") >= 0) {
        var val = $("#higher_edu_count").val();
        $("#higher_edu_count").val(val - 1);
        $(_this).closest('fieldset').remove();
    } else if (classname.indexOf("high-education") >= 0) {
        var val = $("#higher_edu_count").val();
        $("#higher_edu_count").val(val - 1);
        $(_this).closest('fieldset').remove();
    }

}
```

Comment: if this is your code, you forgot to add var infront of it lol" $allErrors = $message.find('.' + this.options.err.clazz.split(' ').join('.') +... "

Comment: check the update question

Comment: $field is either undefined OR doesnt return anything on .closest()

Comment: Yes, Because I remove the html. Please go through to question once again.

Comment: if( $parent ) { } ... in the else case do nothing?

Comment: @MaxBumaye : Which `if` you are talking about?

Comment: dude... something in this code resolves to undefined and it is most likely the first invokation of .closest(row) -> $field.closest(row); So Just check if $parent resolves true (which means that the field exists) and only do your validation THEN!

Comment: and stop using the freakin dollar sign. JS isnt PHP or Perl

Comment: First, the validation js is not written by me. I provided a link in the question from where I use it. 
Second : I tried ` if ($field.closest(row)) {`  but more errors I got like `
SyntaxError: missing : after case label
 

case / ^ [0 - 9A - F]{15}$ / i.test(value):`

Comment: If its not written by you and it works like shit, then obviously dont event use it

Comment: That's good, not able to solve the issue lets vote down it.

Comment: I can tell you how to solve the issue. Delete the code you have written. You are trying to call a method on a function that is not defined. In javascript terms that causes a dump. To avoid calling this dump you can check if your method exists by wrapping it in an if clause like I have stated TWICE above. Downvote because of simple ignorance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87866/discussion-between-max-bumaye-and-urfusion).

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time google chrome store data as cookies and these value will give the same result as long as it is stored. Please try testing in multiple browser or clear the history and run the file.

Answer (score 0):

I go through your problem and tried this http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/. It will be helpful. Use this Javascript code

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#education')
                // Remove button click handler
                .on('click', '.remove-addmore', function () {

                    var index = $(this).attr('id');
                    var $row = $(this).parent('fieldset');

                    $('#education')
                            .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="data[DoctorEducation][' + index + '][title]"]'))
                            .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="data[DoctorEducation][' + index + '][degree_type_id]"]'))
                            .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="data[DoctorEducation][' + index + '][college_hospital]"]'))
                            .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="data[DoctorEducation][' + index + '][start_date]"]'))
                            .formValidation('removeField', $row.find('[name="data[DoctorEducation][' + index + '][end_date]"]'));
                    // Remove element containing the option
                    $(this).parent('fieldset').remove();

                    // Remove field

                });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: let me try this. BTW if you check my code I already tried that.
`  $('#education').formValidation('enableFieldValidators', 'data[DoctorEducation][1][title]', false);`

Comment: now try with "removeField". it might be helpful for you

Comment: Bingo!! Its work like charm.. Thanks for saving my another day.